# truncate or delete all data in table with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

with NHibernateSession.Delete(entity); i can delete entity. How can i truncate or delete all data in table with NHibernate.

i can do with HQL like: session.createQuery ( "truncate tablename"). ExecuteUpdate () but is there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch, data oriented operations are not really what NHibernate is intended for.  You could use session.createSQLQuery() and then just specify whatever SQL you would under normal situations.  However, you should consider whether you really need to use NHibernate for this particular task - it probably doesn't make sense to.

Comment: hmm so you suggest using pure DAO for that.

Comment: Well in my opinion NH only makes sense if you are using an object oriented approach.  If you are thinking in terms of data rows, and wanting to do table wide operations, then NH is simply complicated code that will get in your way.

Comment: @Jajub - I don't know that it works, perhaps it does but to me it does not make sense to use HQL for this kind of thing.